# How to disable the IDE controller on this Asrock AMD motherboard?

Tags: motherboard, bios, pata

I have this motherboard with AMD 710 southbridge: [Asrock 980DE3/U3S3 R2.0](http://www.asrock.com/MB/AMD/980DE3U3S3%20R2.0/index.asp).

I no longer use the IDE/PATA controller, therefore i’d like to disable it to free system resources. I can see the options to disable SATA2 and SATA3 controllers in the BIOS, but none for IDE. Have i overlooked something?

Comment: What makes you think disabling it will generate any measurable performance increase ( it won't ) not even in the slightest

Answer (score 1):

There may be a jumper on the motherboard - look at the manual.

However the ATA controller doesn't occupy any significant amount of resources. Its driver takes a few tens of Kbytes (yes, K, not M). I wouldn't bother.